# Running PHP and Rails apps under the same (Apache) web directory structure

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

My company have several apps running alongside on an Apache2 web server which resides on an Ubuntu server.

Our setup includes:

> - A portal website is set at Apache's document root "/",
> - Another customer service app (written in PHP) resides under a sub directory ("/php_app").

With that setup, everything seems to be working perfectly and smoothly.

However, afterward, there comes another requirement to have another ruby on rails app to be implemented under the same root directory's structure.
and that ruby on rails app should belong under another directory (under the same root) called "/rails_app".
I doubt if this setup achievable?

By the  way, from my quick research, this should be possible by deploying ruby on rails app using Passenger Apache (Please follow the reference article here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/)
The reason we need to put them all under the same directory structure because my company will later need to share authentication system between all apps (SSO or a mechanism of such kind), and what I heard of from googling is it's best that all apps should be put under the same domain.

I need to hear anyone's working experiences on this kind of setup requirements to be shared with or anyone could suggest if my idea is possible or not?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm staring down the same challenge.  Did you make any progress on this?